# how to connect sql and mysql database in a single java program?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

this program is to store the value in mysql database
and retrieve the data from sql server.
mysql database is working.
but sql database was not accessible by this connection.

is it possible to connect two different servers in a single program???

```
package src.ui;

import src.ui.ImageHandler;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AddAccount extends JPanel implements ActionListener, DocumentListener, KeyListener {

    String imagefolder = ImageHandler.returnimagepath();
    Image bgImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(getClass().getResource("/src/ui/images/bgc.jpg"));
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    String iden[] = {"Student","Others"};
    String type[] = {"Account User", "Walkthrough User"};
    JLabel userid = new JLabel("USER ID");
    JLabel name = new JLabel("FULL NAME");
    JLabel pswrd = new JLabel("PASSWORD");
    JLabel ident = new JLabel("IDENTIFICATION");
    JLabel idno = new JLabel("ID NUMBER");
    JLabel Add = new JLabel("ADDRESS");
    JLabel acctype = new JLabel("ACCOUNT TYPE");
    JTextField userFld = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField nameFld = new JTextField(10);
    JPasswordField pswrdFld = new JPasswordField(10);
    JComboBox identC = new JComboBox(iden);
    JComboBox actype = new JComboBox(type);
    JTextField idFld = new JTextField(10);
    JTextArea addArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("RESET");
    JButton b1 = new JButton("SEARCH");
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(addArea);

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/cybman", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //System.out.println(e);
        }
        return conn;
    }
    public static Connection getConnection1() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\BCA1:1433;databaseName=Old_Bhandarkars;user=sa;password=1234");
           // con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-DLR1RBD\\SQLEXPRESS;user=sa;password=1234;database=Members");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SERVER ERROR");
            //System.out.println(e);
        }
        return con;
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void init() {
        setLayout(null);
        okButton.addActionListener(this);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        pswrdFld.addActionListener(this);
        pswrdFld.setEchoChar('*');
        addArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        identC.addActionListener(this);
        actype.addActionListener(this);
        userid.setBounds(270, 20, 120, 20);
        userFld.setBounds(470, 20, 140, 20);
        b1.setBounds(670, 20, 100, 20);
        name.setBounds(270, 70, 120, 20);
        nameFld.setBounds(470, 70, 140, 20);
        pswrd.setBounds(270, 120, 120, 20);
        pswrdFld.setBounds(470, 120, 140, 20);
        ident.setBounds(270, 170, 120, 20);
        identC.setBounds(470, 170, 140, 20);
        idno.setBounds(270, 220, 120, 20);
        idFld.setBounds(470, 220, 140, 20);
        acctype.setBounds(270, 270, 120, 20);
        actype.setBounds(470, 270, 140, 20);
        Add.setBounds(270, 320, 320, 20);
        scroll.setBounds(470, 320, 140, 60);
        okButton.setBounds(270, 410, 100, 20);
        okButton.addKeyListener(this);
        exitButton.setBounds(510, 410, 100, 20);
    }

    public AddAccount() {
        init();
        add(userid);
        add(userFld);
        add(name);
        add(nameFld);
        add(pswrd);
        add(pswrdFld);
        add(ident);
        add(identC);
        add(idno);
        add(idFld);
        add(acctype);
        add(actype);
        add(Add);
        add(b1);
        add(scroll);
        add(okButton);
        add(exitButton);
    }

    public static String now() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
    public class Function
    {
       Connection  con=getConnection1();
     ResultSet rs;  

       public ResultSet find(String s)
       {
           try{

               Statement sta = con.createStatement();
           String s1 = "select * from Members where Fld_Member_Id="+s+"";
         rs = sta.executeQuery(s1);


           }
           catch(Exception ex){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No connection");
               //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
           }
           //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs);
       return rs;
       }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String str = e.getActionCommand();
        char[] pass;
        String uid;
        String nam;
        String add;
        String id;
        String idnum;
        String actyp;
        int amt = 0;
        String datE;
        if (str.equals("SEARCH")) {
            Function f=new Function();
            ResultSet rs=null;
            String n1="name";
            String i1="id1";
            String address="addr";
            uid = userFld.getText();


            if(uid.equals(""))
            {
                JFrame msg=new JFrame();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, "Please enter the user id", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
           // simple.main();
           else
            {
            rs=f.find(userFld.getText());
            try{
                if(rs.next()){
                   nameFld.setText(rs.getString("Fld_First_Name"));
                   idFld.setText(rs.getString("Fld_Member_Id"));
                   addArea.setText(rs.getString("Fld_PAddr"));
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No data");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage());
            }
            }
        }

        if (str.equals("OK")) {


            try {

                uid = userFld.getText();
                nam = nameFld.getText();
                pass = pswrdFld.getPassword();
                add = addArea.getText();
                idnum = idFld.getText();
                id = (String) identC.getSelectedItem();
                actyp = (String) actype.getSelectedItem();
                datE = getDateTime();
                String pwrd = new String(pass);

                Connection conn = getConnection();

                /*ERROR CHECKING*/
                boolean success = true;

                if (uid.equals("")) {
                    JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, "Please enter the user id", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    success = false;
                } else if (nam.equals("")) {
                    JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, "Please enter the name", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    success = false;
                } else if (pwrd.equals("")) {
                    JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, "Please enter the password", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    success = false;
                } else if ((!id.equals("Student")) && (idnum.equals(""))) {
                    JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, "Please enter the identification number", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    success = false;
                } else if (add.equals("")) {
                    JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, "Please enter the address", "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    success = false;
                }

                /*end of ERROR CHECKING*/

                if (success == true) {
                    ///////////ENSURE/////////
                    JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                    int choice;
                    choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(msg, "Are you sure?", "Select your choice", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                    /////////////////////////

                    if (choice == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                        str = "insert into account(userid,name,password,address,identification,identificationnum,amount,dates,acctype" + ") values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(str);

                        ps.setString(1, uid);
                        ps.setString(2, nam);
                        ps.setString(3, pwrd);
                        ps.setString(4, add);
                        ps.setString(5, id);
                        ps.setString(6, idnum);
                        ps.setInt(7, amt);
                        ps.setString(8, datE);
                        ps.setString(9, actyp);

                        int count;
                        count = ps.executeUpdate();
                        count++;
                        count--;

                        //////////////////////////////
                        ReportPanel.userC.addItem(uid);
                        ViewAccount.userC.addItem(uid);

                        if (actyp.equals("Account User")) {
                            RechargePanel.userC.addItem(uid);
                        }
                        //////////////////////////////

                        JFrame msg1 = new JFrame();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg1, "An account has been successfully created", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } else if (choice == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, "Account Creation Aborted", "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                //conn.close();


            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                String error;
                JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                //error=e1.toString();
                error = "Your entry for user id already exists";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, error, "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                String error;
                JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                error = e1.toString();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, error, "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }

        }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////     
        if (str.equals("RESET")) {
            try {
                userFld.setText("");
                nameFld.setText("");
                pswrdFld.setText("");
                addArea.setText("");
                idFld.setText("");
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                String error;
                JFrame msg = new JFrame();
                error = e2.toString();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(msg, error, "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        //
    }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
        if (key.getSource() == pswrdFld) {
            if (key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            }
        }
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {
       //
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why you cannot have connections to two databases from one Java program.  What error, if any, do you get?

Comment: (1-) Well why don't you display the Exception to help you debug the problem?

Comment: It should be very possible.  as @camickr said show us the exception stack you are getting and what type of errors are occurring.  Since the MySQL side is working, turn that off and simply start troubleshooting the SQL Server side.

Comment: these are all errors i got.                                                                                    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is.misc.URLClassPath$Jar empty

Comment: reason to do these type of connection is to retrieve the data from database and set it to specified textbox

Comment: @Dale if i turned off mysql then login not possible sir, because entire thing is made by mysql and only these part of program is used to retrieve the data from sql server. if i stop mysql server then we can't do nothing.

Comment: It seems to be jar problem, and not the code. Try deleting and getting a fresh copy of the jar?

Comment: when i try to add jdbc driver to netbeans. these errors are occured.          Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver:// using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl)